# Game of Life component in React

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react.js, game-of-life

I have been learning webdevelopment at Freecodcamp and have therefore been writing a lot of javascript by myself. They have a code-review chatroom, but the people in that chatroom seem to review the final product and not the code itself.

So, I am searching for some constructive criticism about the structure and style of my code.

The code shown below is a class from a Game of Life game as part of the Freecodecamp course and does work. It is written in Javascript and uses React. There is more code for this project, but I don't think it is necessary to show all of the code, for you to critique my code structure and style. If it the rest of the code is required I can of course post it as well.

```
class GameOfLife extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.toggleGameState = this.toggleGameState.bind(this);
    this.stepGame = this.stepGame.bind(this);
    this.squareClicked = this.squareClicked.bind(this);
    this.clearGrid = this.clearGrid.bind(this);
    this.generateRandomGrid = this.generateRandomGrid.bind(this);
    this.toggleSpeed = this.toggleSpeed.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      cellRows: generateRandomCellDistribution({height: 50, width: 50}), 
      size: {height:50, width:50}, 
      gameState: 'playing', speed: 1,
      generation: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({gamteState: 'playing', interval: setInterval(this.stepGame, 200/this.state.speed)});
  }

  toggleGameState() {
    var newState = this.state.gameState === 'playing' ? 'paused' : 'playing';
    if(newState === 'playing') {
      this.setState({gameState: newState, interval: setInterval(this.stepGame, 200/this.state.speed)});
    } else {
      this.setState({'gameState': newState});
      clearInterval(this.state.interval);
    }
  }

  squareClicked(row, column) {
    var cellRows = this.state.cellRows.slice();
    var newState = cellRows[row][column].state === 'alive' ? 'dead' : 'alive';
    cellRows[row][column] = {state: newState};
    this.setState({cellRows: cellRows});
  }

  generateRandomGrid() {
    this.setState({cellRows: generateRandomCellDistribution(this.state.size), generation: 0})
  }

  clearGrid() {
    this.setState({cellRows: getBlankCellRows(this.state.size), generation: 0});
  }

  toggleSpeed(){
    var newSpeed = this.state.speed < 4 ? this.state.speed+1 : 1;
    clearInterval(this.state.interval);
    this.setState({speed: newSpeed, interval: setInterval(this.stepGame, 200/newSpeed)});
  }

  stepGame() {
    var newCellRows = getBlankCellRows(this.state.size);
    var currentCellRows = this.state.cellRows.slice();
    var aliveNeighbours = getAliveNeighbours(currentCellRows);

    for(var i = 0; i < currentCellRows.length; i++) {
      for(var q = 0; q < currentCellRows[i].length; q++) {
        newCellRows[i][q].state = getNewState(currentCellRows[i][q].state, getAliveNeighbours(currentCellRows, i, q));
      }
    }

    this.setState({cellRows: newCellRows, generation: this.state.generation + 1});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="ui-container"> 
          <button className="button-theme" onClick={this.toggleGameState}>{this.state.gameState === 'playing' ? 'Pause' : 'Start'}</button>
          <button className="button-theme" onClick={this.clearGrid}>Clear grid</button>
          <button className="button-theme" onClick={this.generateRandomGrid}>Random</button>
          <button className="button-theme" onClick={this.toggleSpeed}>Speed: {this.state.speed}x</button>
          <div className="generation-indicator">Generation: {this.state.generation}</div>
        </div>
        <Grid 
          gameState={this.state.gameState} 
          size={this.state.size} 
          cellRows={this.state.cellRows} 
          squareClicked={this.squareClicked}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Good: Object properties are in a logical order 
// (alphabetical order isn't always best)
this.state = {
  cellRows: generateRandomCellDistribution({height: 50, width: 50}), 
  size: {height:50, width:50}, 
  gameState: 'playing', 
  speed: 1,       // This property should be on its own line like the rest.
  generation: 0
};

// Style should be consistent (Source: Code Complete)
// Object properties on their own lines like above
// (even as parameters).
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    gamteState: 'playing',
    // No magic numbers (Source: Code Complete)
    // Why 200/speed? What does that represent?
    // Assign a variable above like var tickSpeed = 200/this.state.speed
    // Something to explain why you're doing the division.
    // Even better would be to put that in another function
    // to be used in all places you do this conversion. 
    interval: setInterval(this.stepGame, 200/this.state.speed)
  });
}

// Function name should describe what the function does
// (rather than what triggers it) (Source: Code Complete)
squareClicked(row, column)  -->  handleClickInSquare(row, column) or updateStateForCell(row, column)

// Same here. Function doesn't just return a random grid, 
// it changes the grid to be a random grid (affects state).
generateRandomGrid()  -->  setGridToRandomGrid() or randomizeGrid()

// This one is pretty good, but toggle usually refers to 
// something with two options like Caps Lock (Source: Google define).
// This is tricky and you might think up an even better name that
// includes the facts that you're increasing the speed, there are 
// several options, and it wraps around back to the first option.
toggleSpeed()  -->  cycleSpeed(), increaseSpeedOrWrap(), or selectNextFasterSpeed()

// It's better to select clear iterators although it's not
// uncommon to see i, j, and k. Not sure what q is, though.
// How about i --> row, q --> cell. (Source: Code Complete)
// I've changed the code to demonstrate my suggestions.
// I also recommend using currentCellGrid or similar
// to make it clear that you have a 2D array.
for(var row = 0; row < currentCellGrid.length; row++) {
  // Here you could add a variable to clarify what currentCellGrid[row] is.
  // Use more variables to document what the code is doing.
  // (Source: Code Complete)
  var currentRowCells = currentCellGrid[row];
  for(var cell = 0; cell < currentRowCells.length; cell++) {
    newCellGrid[row][cell].state = getNewState(currentRowCells[cell].state, getAliveNeighbours(currentCellGrid, row, cell));
  }
}
```